# Precursor to Serre's criterion in Eisenbud

Tags: commutative-algebra

Theorem $11.2$ in Eisenbud states the following:

> A Noetherian domain $R$ is normal iff for every prime $P$ of $R$ associated to a principal ideal, $P_P$ is principal.

Since $R$ is an integral domain, then for any principal ideal $Q=(r)$, the associated primes must all be zero since an integral domain has no zero divisors. Furthermore, localizing $0$ at $0$ is just zero...

What is going on here??

Comment: Did you try looking for "associated'' in the index to see what is meant?  (Obviously the interpretation you give isn't the correct one.)    I don't have a copy of the book, but looking at the discussion preceding the theorem on google books, I would guess that it means an associated prime of $R/I$ (for a principal ideal $I$).    A little googling seemed to confirm this.

Comment: Ok. I am using the definition from Chapter 3.  I don't quite see how you gathered the correct definition from the preceding theorem but I'll take it. Thanks!

Comment: @user7090 In the paragraph right after the definition of associated primes, Eisenbud writes that the associated primes of an ideal $I$ will be understood to mean the associated primes of $R/I$.

Answer (score 0):

In the paragraph right after the definition of associated primes, Eisenbud writes that the associated primes of an ideal $I$ will be understood to mean the associated primes of $R/I$.